# Thread isAlive() returning false

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread call `myThread`.

`public class MyThread extends Thread {}`

Now I put `myThread` to the constructor of `Thread`.

```
MyThread myThread = MyThread();
Thread thread= new Thread(myThread, "myThread");
```

So when I call `thread.start()`, it will evoke the run method of `myThread`.
When `myThread` run method is still running, I checked `myThread.isAlive()`. It returns false but `thread.isAlive()` returns true.
Why `myThread.isAlive()` is returning false?

Comment: It would be less convoluted if you showed us the code, rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: Your `myThread` thread is never started. You're confusing everything by making your `MyThread` class uselessly extend `Thread`.

Comment: Ok.....so it was not started.....but its run method was evoked?

Comment: If myThread is not runnable, I can't add it to thead constructor

Comment: Then make the class implement `Runnable`. It doesn't need to extend `Thread`.

Comment: ok......but still myThread.isAlive() will be false

Comment: If you do the above there is no `isAlive`. Call `isAlive` on `thread`.

Comment: OK...thanks.....I will check thread only